# C - int function returning ascii value

Tags: c, function, integer, arguments, argv

I wrote a C function that is supposed to iterate over the argument vector and once it finds the *irow* argument, it's to read the integer in the next argument so it can be used later on in the *main* method:

```
int insertRow(char*argv[], int row_number) {
    row_number = 0;
    for(int i = 0; argv[i]; i++) {
        if ( isdigit(argv[i][0]) && (strcmp(argv[i - 1], "irow") == 0) )
            row_number = argv[i][0];
    }
    printf("%d\n", row_number);
    return row_number;
}
```

However, when I run the program:

```
./main irow 4
```

it prints 52(the ascii table for 4). How can I fix the function so it returns the *integer* 4?

Comment: Perhaps `row_number = argv[i][0] - '0';`?

Comment: @harvey This function declaration int insertRow(char*argv[], int row_number) {
    row_number = 0; does not make a sense. The value of the second parameter is not used.

Comment: @RetiredNinja thank you,it works, will remember that trick.

Comment: `for(int i = 0;` ... `argv[i - 1]` looks like a bug. Why compare the previous argv string? What if the first one starts with a digit? You get out of bounds access.

Answer (score 2):

```
printf("%c\n", row_number);
```

numbers stored in a string are stored in their ascii values. If you print the value as a number (`%d`) you will show the ascii value. If you print the value as a character (`%c`), you will interpret the number to the matching character, in this case, a number digit